# HDMI or DisplayPort through USB-C?

Tags: usb-c, hdmi

I want to get video output through USB-C from Raspberry Compute Module 4. I can get HDMI output from Rasp CM4, but I am not sure that HDMI Alt Mode works fine on USB-C (and I can't find hardware to create this).

I have read here that Texas Instruments don't have PD Controller that supports HDMI Alt Mode.

https://e2e.ti.com/support/interface-group/interface/f/interface-forum/896000/tps65987d-hdmi-source-over-type-c

Is the best option to use an HDMI to DisplayPort converter to be sure that this will work fine on USB-C?

Comment: TI TUSB546A-DC and possibly similar chips supports HDMI Alt Mode (see [application note](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slla333/slla333.pdf?ts=1631774711247)). However, to the best of my knowledge, HDMI Alt Mode is rarely used and not well supported by displays. So better check for compatibility before you invest in this design.

Comment: And what do you plan to have on the other end of Type-C cable, as recipient?

Comment: @Ale..chenski a PC

Comment: I've read in the USB-C specs that HDMI is a supported alternate mode but it uses all four high speed data lines.  If you want to preserve a pair of those data lines for USB 3.x data then you can't use HDMI.  There's two other video alternate modes, and they both allow sharing the port with USB 3.x, MHL and DisplayPort.  Is preserving USB 3.x important?